# Does selenium 4 evolutions work for chrome 95?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, devtools, selenium4

When I execute this code :

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//40 3
    
DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
    
Map<String,Object>coordinates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    
coordinates.put("latitude", 40.427939382087814);
coordinates.put("longitude", -3.7056416054815884);
coordinates.put("accuracy", 1);
driver.executeCdpCommand("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", coordinates);
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Chrome don't change the location : selenium4, chrome 95

Message in console :

> WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 95, so returning the closest version found: 91
> oct. 28, 2021 4:13:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
> INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 95 of 91

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps or is relevant. I placed your settings into my selenium 4 project ChromeDriverFactory.class and I never got the 'Warning' that you can see. My browser is also v95.0.4638.54. I didn't get a chance to check location details yet, but I noticed in my .m2 repository, for selenium 4 I do have the following: selenium-devtools-v85, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93 and 95. Do you have the same ?

Comment: hello, yes i have that folders. i will try to change chrome cersion and verify if it changes the location.

Comment: when i try : driver.get("https://my-location.org/");
it gives me the location in the script ,   but with   driver.get("http://google.com"); gives me my real location

Comment: It seems that it detects the location , because when i seach in google it gives me the choices adapted to that location , but google gives me my correct location (in the bottom right.).  thakyou @djmonki for your help